# HiveServer2 failed to start

Tags: hadoop

I deployed hadoop using ambari 1.6.1.While starting HiveServer2,I am getting below error.Similar error for YARN and MapReduce2 too.Please help me out.

Fail: Execution of ‘hadoop fs -mkdir rpm -q hadoop | grep -q "hadoop-1" || echo "-p" /apps/hive/warehouse /user/hive && hadoop fs -chmod 777 /apps/hive/warehouse && hadoop fs -chmod 700 /user/hive && hadoop fs -chown hive /apps/hive/warehouse /user/hive’ returned 1. mkdir: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).

Answer (score 0):

Execute the commands directly through command line the check the issue.

> hadoop fs -mkdir rpm -q hadoop | grep -q "hadoop-1" || echo "-p" /apps/hive/warehouse /user/hive
>
> hadoop fs -chmod 777 /apps/hive/warehouse
>
> hadoop fs -chmod 700 /user/hive && hadoop fs -chown hive /apps/hive/warehouse /user/hive

If something goes wrong you will get an error in the first command itself. Do share the result.

Was the deployment of components successful before you started the components ?